# Why there is gap between menu block in safari but not in chrome , mozilla , opera etc. browser?

Tags: html, css

When i run this code on different browsers , then on browsers like firefox, chrome, opera etc. , it is fine but when i run this code on safari web browser , then there is a gap between top nav blocks, why?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav {
  width: 90%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.top-nav {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}
.top-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14.28571428571429%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
}
.top-nav > li.active > a {
  color: #CBD2D4;
}
.top-nav > li:hover,
.sub-nav > li:hover {
  color: white;
}
.top-nav > li a {
  font-family: 'Baumans', serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: #CBD2D4;
}
.top-nav > li a {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid #3c3c3c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid #3c3c3c;
}
.top-nav > li > a:hover,
.sub-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #FD954F;
}
.sub-nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 99999;
}
.top-nav li:hover .sub-nav {
  visibility: visible;
}
.sub-nav > li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.sub-nav > li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid #3c3c3c;
}
.sub-nav > li:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
.sub-nav > li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/

.top-nav li a:hover + .hidden,
.hidden:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <ul class="top-nav" id="menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="djakhiltalreja_home.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Music</a>
      <ul class="sub-nav hidden">
        <li><a href="djakhiltalreja_single_music.php">Single</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="djakhiltalreja_album_music.php">Album</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="djakhiltalreja_video.php">Video</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">New Release</a>
      <ul class="sub-nav hidden">
        <li><a href="djakhiltalreja_single_newrelease.php">Single</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="djakhiltalreja_album_newrelease.php">Album</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="djakhiltalreja_video_newrelease.php">Video</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="djakhiltalreja_image.php">Image</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="djakhiltalreja_partymap.php">Partymap</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="djakhiltalreja_contactus.php">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but it's working fine for me on Safari 5.1.7 (Windows) - http://jsfiddle.net/8fxs9e6q/embedded/result/

Comment: but adding float:left to .top-nav li , height of <nav> element is showing 0px , why ?

Comment: add `display: inline-block;` and `width: 100%;` to `.top-nav` - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tnguyf2L/) and [Full Screen](http://jsfiddle.net/tnguyf2L/embedded/result/) **OR** add `overflow: hidden;` to `.top-nav`

Comment: this is our link [link](http://akhil.djmusicweb.com) , menu bar works fine in chrome but now in others browser relative to responsive design , first open this kink and then resize window width to smaller for responsive menu , and select new release -> video , i can't be able to select it , why ???

Comment: i have changed all that what u had said , but can't be able to select new release -> video.... ???

Comment: Mozilla Firefox & Opera doesn't work , but in chrome , it works ???

Comment: thank you so much @MaryMelody :)!!! , now it works in all major browsers...!!!

Comment: but in opera mobile browser , we still have so much difficulties :( !!!

Comment: Just try one more time maybe that works on opera - http://jsfiddle.net/bhhuuw3j/

Comment: ya it works in all computer web browsers very well :) , but in mobile , opera mini browser giving me so much difficulties :( !!!

Comment: What are the issues on opera browser (mobile) show me an image and please explain the issues?

Comment: First Issue :- Background Image Doesn't occur in full page , when scrolling down , background image disappears ???

Comment: Okay in that case you should ask a new question on SO. I think, I can't help you with mobile browsers. Sorry and Good Luck! :)

Comment: okk for that issue , i will post another question , but when we hover on music menu then home is also selected on opera mobile browser , why ???

Comment: Sorry but I don't have opera mobile browser so I can't check the issue.

Comment: okk , again thank you so much for all ur help @MaryMelody !!! :)

Comment: @MaryMelody ,  If You Don't Mind , Can We Be Friends On Facebook :) ???

Comment: @MaryMelody , need your help to solve css3 animation problem in firefox browser , there are two images in cardflip animation , but only one image in flipping again and again in mozilla firefox , but in others browsers , it works well , here is the link :- http://shireen.djmusicweb.com/index%203107.php

Comment: @MaryMelody , now it's solved , leave it :) !!!